# Table with 600 000+ rows in CakePhp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have to do a sql request on a table (MySQL) with 600 000+ rows with CakePHP.
I'm testing in local how I can handle with this huge table.

With CakePHP when I first tried a simple `->find('all')`, I had many errors with buffers sizes.
I add

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
set_time_limit(0);
```

in my index.php

Now, my page is loading a long time then crash.

When I try `->find('first')` to get just the first row, same thing : the page loads a long time and encounters an error after.

Have you some ideas about that ?

Comment: Performing a find('all') on 600,000+ records is a bit too much. Have you tried adding conditions and a limit ?

Comment: Have you tried debug the query without running it? Won't "first" make `limit 1` query?

Comment: @InigoFlores yes that's why i change to find('first') but the problem is the same, I don't know why.

Comment: @Tsumannai I tried debug the query but nothing change

Comment: Please post any relationships you have set in your models, as what you describe might be a consequence of having incorrectly defined relationships. If this is the case, calling `$this->Model->contain()` before the `find()` should make the error go away (don't forget to load de `Containable` behavior in the model). The same can be achieved by setting `$this->Model->recursive = -1` before the `find()`.

Comment: @InigoFlores The table doesn't have model. That's why I was questioning me about how CakePHP is handling the table. By the way, my problem is fixed. It seems that close the page and open a new tab fix the long loading problem. If I do a find('first'), it works as I want, now I just have to define conditions, and not retry to display 600 000+ records.

Answer (score 4):

> Have you some ideas about that ?

1. Paginate it.
2. If you can't paginate it you'll have to implement a job queue that does it on the server side in the background and generate the document and then provide it to the user as download.

It is pretty obvious that you can't process a huge set of data without running into some technical limitations. By 600k rows, depending on how they're rendered, even the client (browser) will probably become terrible slow.

Change your approach to this, it's not going to work well this way. Or put a few 
hundred gigabyte of RAM into your server.

Setting `ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");` is **never** a solution but a fugly workaround. Instead make sure that your script always works within some predefined boundaries. This will just make sure the script blows up on a server with 64mb but work on one with 128mb and later blow up on the one with 128mb as well when you get more data.

Comment: yes the ini_set was just to test if my request work or not. I have to do some statistics with the data, I will try do the final request and retry

Comment: Use SQL to calculate your statistics instead of fetching all data and iterating over it? That's a perfect job for a DB!

Comment: that's what I will do :)